# How does Spark Sql Parse Json?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working with Spark SQL and am considering using data contained within `JSON datasets`. I am aware of the `.jsonFile()` method in Spark SQL.

I have two questions:

1. What is the general strategy used by Spark SQL `.jsonFile()`  to parse/decode a JSON dataset?
2. What are some other general strategies to parsing/decoding JSON datasets?

(Example of an answers I'm looking for is that the `JSON` file is read into an `ETL` pipeline and transformed into a predefined data structure.)

Thanks.